# Avoid fake credit cards using stripe

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a 7 day free trial in my app but many people are adding fake credit cards that get declined when the trial is over. Is there a way to use the stripe api to charge the card for a small amount and refund the payment afterward to make sure the credit card is valid? Or some other way. I want stripe to stop accepting invalid credit cards

Comment: Enable the strictest checks then make sure all payments require the 3D Secure check, Issue with stripe is it's easy for card testers to use all day long if you don't implement physical location, user, address, cards tried etc checks before allowing entering the cards, issue with taking a small charge and refunding is if its a stolen card your going to get chargeback fees anyways which will perhaps be more than the service charge, there is better gateways

Comment: If you write in to Stripe support they may be able to look at your fake card declines and suggest other mitigation methods that are more tailored to the issue that you have seen https://support.stripe.com/?contact=true

Comment: Also it is worth noting that Stripe will often do test $0 or $1 charges on the cards that you save with them. You can manually make your own other charges and refund them or place a hold on funds and release them. The cards you have saved for subscriptions will work like any other Stripe card. If you go down that path, be sure to be crystal clear to your users that your temporary charges will show up https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method https://stripe.com/docs/payments/place-a-hold-on-a-payment-method